# failing to insert a tree in a sorted treelist

Tags: ocaml, sortedlist

I am trying to insert a tree in a sorted tree list with the following code :

```
exception NilTree;;
type hTree = Nil | Node of char * int * hTree * hTree;;

let rec printTree t = match t with
    | Nil -> ()
    | Node(c, w, l, r) -> print_char c ; print_int w ; printTree l ; printTree r;;

let rec printTreeList l = match l with
    | [] -> ()
    | h::t -> print_newline (printTree h) ; printTreeList t;;

let insertree l tree = 
    let rec insertree' l tree prev = match tree with 
        | Nil -> raise NilTree
        | Node(c, w, left, right) -> match l with
            | [] -> prev@[tree]
            | h::t -> match h with 
                | Nil -> raise NilTree
                | Node(c', w', left', right') -> 
                    if  w <= w' then 
                        prev@[tree]@[h]@t 
                    else 
                        insertree' t tree prev@[h]
    in insertree' l tree [];;

let tree1 = insertree [Node('a', 3, Nil, Nil)] (Node('b', 5, Nil, Nil));;
printTreeList tree1;;
```

the trees have four fields, and a tree with a smaller int should be placed before the others,
but here is what I get :

```
b5
a3
```

Comment: In printTree, wouldn't you want to print the left subtree first, then the current node, and then the right subtree?

Answer (score 1):

your statement

```
insertree' t tree prev@[h]
```

is actually interpreted as

```
(insertree' t tree prev) @ [h]
```

because function applications bind stronger than operators. So you need to rewrite this as,

```
insertree' t tree (prev @ [h])
```